# How to open a mysql port for 2 server connected in LAN

Tags: centos, mysql, firewall

I have 2 servers connected togheter in LAN, and both on external network too. One eth0 and the other eth1 adapter.
On both servers I've installed mysql.
I'm able from both server to connect to their respective mysqls using localhost and 192.168.1.x as host but as soon as I try to connect from one server to the mysql of the other server, the port is not reachable.
The servers local IPs are 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2
The ping works correctly so the problem is not related to the LAN adapter configuration.

Here are the firewall configurations:
Note: I'm mostly interested to connect from server 1 to server 2 (mysql).

Server 1 firewall:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [229:43039]
:INPUT ACCEPT [229:43039]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [209:27612]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [208:27552]
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:176]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:60]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [158:20763]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Server 2 firewall:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [48:5312]
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

-- my.cnf of server 2 with mysql

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get? What is the output of `netstat -lntp`? Can you edit those in? BTW, your firewall rules don't do anything, the INPUT policy is set to except. Also, remember that MySQL needs a separate user for external access (user@'%' will do). But, if that were the problem, you'd get 'permission denied'.

Comment: No errors. Just timeout that means that port is unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

> -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

All packets reaching that line will be rejected. All the rules after it will be ignored.

Further reading: [iptables rules ordering](https://serverfault.com/search?q=iptables%20rules%20order)

Comment: I had completely overlooked that...

Comment: I tried to put that line at the end but nothing changed. Maybe should I open the 3306 ports on server 1 too ?

Comment: Yes I needed to open output port on server 1 too. Thank you for your help. Without your help I would stay here for another week without solving the problem.